# How can I include a comment in GNU Radio Companion?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

Especially when making examples to distribute with out of tree modules, I'd like to include comments in the flow graph. That is, I'd like to include text with no effect on the generated code.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In any block’s properties, under the Advanced tab, there is a field called “Comment”. This text will be displayed below the block.
2. You can use the block **Core → Misc → Note** which allows you to put arbitrary text in its “Name” field.

Neither of these puts any comments or anything else into the generated code.

Comment: To add to Kevin's answer, in some versions of GR 3.8, the default for 'Show Block Comments' is off, so to see them, the user must click View -> 'Show Block Comments' to see them.